# Bayes' rule for mixed discrete and multiple continuous random variables

Tags: conditional-probability, discrete-distributions, bayes-rule

Consider the Bernoulli random variable $Z$ that takes $z=1$ with probability $1/2$ and $z=0$ otherwise. A different random variable, $X$, is defined on $x \in [0,1]$ has the following conditional distribution:

$$
f_{X|Z}(x|z) = \left\{ \begin{array}{lc} 2x, & z=1 \\ 2-2x, & z=0 \end{array} \right.
$$

(A realization of $X$ is thus a signal of $Z$, in the sense that higher realizations of $X$ are more likely when $Z=1$ and less likely otherwise.)

I am struggling to apply Bayes' rule to these random variables when more than one $X$ is drawn independently. Suppose that $X_1, X_2$ are drawn independently conditional on the same realization of $Z$. Without too much difficulty, one can derive that $F_X(x) = x \iff f_X(x) = 1 \iff f_{X_1 X_2}(x_1,x_2) = 1$. Bayes' rule should them imply

\begin{align}
f_{Z|X_1, X_2}(z|X_1, X_2) & = f_{X_1, X_2|Z}(x_1, x_2 | z) f_Z(z) \frac{1}{f_{X_1X_2}(X_1, X_2)} \\
&= f_{X_1, X_2|Z}(x_1, x_2 | z) \cdot \frac{1}{2} \cdot 1 \\
&= \left\{ \begin{array}{lc} 2x_1x_2, & z=1 \\ 2(1-x_1)(1-x_2), & z = 0  \end{array} \right.
\end{align}

where the last equality uses independence, i.e. $f_{X_1X_2|Z} = f_{X_1|z}f_{X_2|Z}$. This doesn't make sense to me, however, since adding up this conditional PMF doesn't yield 1:

$$
f_{Z|X_1X_2}(z = 0 | \cdot) + f_{Z|X_1X_2}(z = 1 | \cdot) = 2x_1x_2 + 2(1-x_1)(1-x_2) \neq 1
$$

I'm sure I'm making a very basic conceptual error somewhere here. Thanks in advance for your help!